# Django settings import error

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm getting an import error from apache running on RHEL server

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'FLWeb.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings
```

The app run properly with django server and also works on a CentOS 7 machine (with apache and mod_wsgi).

my wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
sys.path.insert(0, root)

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = 'FLWeb.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

the .conf file

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess localhost python-path=/home/evtdb/FLWeb:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup localhost

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>

        <Directory /home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Files>
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried different "sys.path" options on wsgi.py to import settings but just doesnt work

full error log

```
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=38788): Target WSGI script '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=38788): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     django.setup()
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._setup(name)
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
[Wed Feb 25 09:22:10 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'FLWeb.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings
```

**EDIT**

Problem was settings.py permissions, i changed them to 644. Now i got this error

```
[Wed Feb 25 17:23:45 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Wed Feb 25 17:23:45 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Wed Feb 25 17:23:45 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: Your `settings.py` is in `/home/evtdb/FLWeb` or `/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb` ?

Comment: in `/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb` , same directory than `wsgi.py`

Comment: is there `__init__.py` in `/home/evtdb/FLWeb/` ?

Comment: no, that is "just a folder", the `__init__.py` is on `/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb`

Comment: Please print `sys.path` before `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]` in your wsgi file. This might be path issue.

Comment: `['..', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`

Comment: previous path was after execute python wsgi.py.  From the apache log I got 
`['/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/..', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/..', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/..', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb', '/home/evtdb/FLWeb']
`

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was about file permissions. As I didnt got a `"(13) Permission Denied":`  wasnt as evident as it should be.

Check this https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

> Typical permissions on a unix-like system for resources not owned by the User or Group specified in httpd.conf would be 644 rw-r--r- for ordinary files and 755 drwxr-x-r-x for directories or CGI scripts. You may also need to check extended permissions (such as SELinux permissions) on operating systems that support them.